# Do I need to use singleton of GADRequest() in navigation controller child view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, singleton, admob

I am new to Admob. I am implementing Admob and want to add an ad in a `TableView` cell in a child view of `navigationViewController`.

I wonder to know is it necessary to create a singleton of `GADRequest()` because the `TableView` cell will be reused when scroll the `TableView` and also frequently push and pop navigation view will keep creating and destroy instance of `GADRequest` frequently? Does it affect the performance of Admob?

Someone told me if creating more than one request within 12 seconds, Google will regards it as cheating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Pushing and popping is definitely not a problem and you dont need a
>   singleton request for it.
>
> Other thing for the `TableViewCell` , i would advise to make separate
>   reusable cell index for the normal table cell and for the
>   advertisement cell. That way , the cell will be reused and you dont
>   need to recreate GADView everytime.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean extending  UITableviewCell and create the GADView in side the class rather than initialising GADView in cellForRowAtIndexPath ?  But the customised subclass of UITableviewCells still be reused when scroll tableview. The request of that cell will still be destroyed. right?

Comment: are you using storyboard and dynamic prototypes for the cell ?

Comment: Yes, I use storyboard and dynamic prototypes

Comment: okay then make two different prototype of cells. one is for your data and other for your adview cell. the adview cell will probably throw off screen error when it goes out of screen. i would suggest to also see if you can replace the adview banner with some kind of static animated banner that then opens a full screen ad since having a advertisement inside scrollview is definitely problematic for your epcm ratio

Comment: Sorry I got a wrong concept with uitableview reusable cell. I thought the instances of tableviewcell, including customised subclass of UITableViewCell, will be destroyed when scroll the tableview. Actually, by using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, the instance of the tableviewcell will not be destroyed and of courser it will not create a new request.